# Windows Server 2012 PHP cron

Tags: php, nginx, cron, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I have an nginx server installed on Windows Server and I am wondering how can I run a PHP script using scheduled tasks or [at](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html) every minute? Also how can I use include() within that script? Will including `dirname(__FILE__);` before the include path work the same way as it does with cron?

Comment: If you want to run `Scheduled Tasks` on windows look up `Task Scheduler` in `Control panel -> Administative Tools`

Comment: I know where to find them, I know how to use Windows...

Comment: I now realise you dont need any help but just because I cannot help myself, this post may be of some small assistance, just to jog your memory of course. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/windows-scheduler-to-run-a-task-every-x-minutes

Comment: Way to be a douche, I guess I'll have to find out for myself since no tutorials on how to do it exist.

Comment: Thanks for being such a pleasant human being. It's likely you have already found this but just in case here's a microsoft technet tutorial http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx