# execute c# unit test cases without visual studio and executing them in intervals

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, unit-testing, load-testing

I have developed unit test cases in c# using visual studio 2010 ultimate SP1, i have a requirement such that , i need to execute them without VS2010 and need to control the order and time of execution, Is there any scheduler which fulfill the said requirement.For eg : i need to execute for eg: TestCase1 for every 5 min, Testcase2 for every 10 min etc...The intention is to check load on server and performance evaluation.Unit test cases are developed for WCF operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you meant by "to check load on server" but I suppose that you're talking about load testing, anyway:

I think that tool which would fulfill your requirement is [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server.

You could set up build agent which would build your project and run tests at the end. In most of the popular CI server you can configure how often builds are executed.

If you think that configuring CI server is overkill for you. You can simply use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). This [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/windows-scheduler-to-run-a-task-every-x-minutes) tell how to configure it execute task every x-minutes.
Then you could run your test from standalone executor. Every unit test framework has such tool.

One more point about your tests. It seems that they're rather integration tests than unit tests since they're run on working system rather than single, isolated unit of code.

Comment: A continuous integration server really doesn't feel like the right solution for a load testing problem.  Why would I want to update and build my code if the goal was simply to run a suite of tests.

Comment: You don't really need to update and build the code. This was overview of CI capabilities. You can execute your tests only.

Comment: Thanks folks, my intention was developing unit test case, due to lot of wiring in application i end up developing integrations test cases,hope windows task scheduler would by the suggestion for me , is it?

Comment: Yes, Task Scheduler will do in your scenario.

Comment: I should create batch file with the commands to execute test cases right, I have many test cases. I want to execute TC's selectively on need basis, How can i select specific TC's and how can i create a batch file to execute them?? It seems silly but i am fresher to industry , i need some help