# Find and remove specific text from CSV file with batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a CSV file with many rows and columns (like an Excel file), I want a batch file that can find 'PaperCut Print Logger - http://www.papercut.com/' from first row-first column and if it exists, removed it.Also i want batch file makes a new CSV without that row and with other content.
Also I want this file to be executed whenever a row is added to the table.

what can i do for that???
i want batch file coding.

[image: this image is a part of my CSV file]

Comment: Fine, and what's the question?

Comment: Why not just write something in VBA that uses the `Worksheet_Change` sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have to use Batch, there is a single command for that:

```
find /v "PaperCut Print Logger" <Input.csv > Output.csv
```

which will technically delete *all* lines, that contain the string `PaperCut Print Logger`, but I guess, that fits your needs.

`makes a new CSV without that row and with other Content`? new Content for the first line only?

```
echo this is the new first line>Output.csv
find /v "PaperCut Print Logger" <Input.csv >>Output.csv
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works but not completely! Fine could remove my  "PaperCut Print Logger" string but added 2 line new above all other data! (1 empty row and 1 row with #NAME?), i dont want these 2 too .how can remove them and make a new file without these tow row ???

Comment: oh sorry, my fault. Use a different method to give the file to `find`. See my edit.

Comment: do you know how can i define a time schedule with Windows Time Scheduler that run my bat file every 30mins ???

Comment: [Start], enter `task Scheduler` into the search box (if you have an english Windows -  and execute it.

Comment: Yes I know this program, but i want to schedule my batch file to run every x-minutes.

Comment: I found my resolve on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/windows-scheduler-to-run-a-task-every-x-minutes ThankXx

Comment: [create Task] (not [create Basic Task]. Go to the [Triggers] tab, [New], "daily", "Repeat Task every:"