# Running a batch script every 15 minutes

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have the following script:

```
mkdir Iperf\separate_logs
mkdir Iperf\timestamps

title Setting date and time
echo %DATE% - %TIME% > Iperf\timestamps\iPerf3.log

title [RUNNING] iPerf3
cmd /C "iperf3 -c ip address " > Iperf\separate_logs\iPerf3.log

done;
```

How to make this script run every 15 minutes?

Comment: One way would be to use the scheduler. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4249542/3919155).

Comment: An alternative was to create a caller script that has got a `goto` loop with `call "your-batch-file.bat"` and `timeout /T 900 /NOBREAK` inside...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Task Scheduler application in Windows.

Reference: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7