# how can i execute python code every hour

Tags: python, gpio

I'm working on a "WeatherLogger" app that will create a log file every hour/day.
This is my code:

```
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
rainsensorpin = "4"
GPIO.setup(rainsensorpin, GPIO.IN)
def log():
        print "[!] Log action executed, processing it..."
        filename = time.strftime('%d%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor,pin)
        temp = "{:0.1f}*C".format(temperature)
        hum = "{:0.1f}%".format(humidity)
        state = GPIO.input(rainsensorpin)
        data = "Temp: ", temp, " Hum: ", hum, " Rain: ", state, " Date+Time: ", filename
        os.chdir("logs")
        os.mknod(filename)
        print "[+] Successfully created file: ", filename
```

Is there any way to execute this code every hour, or every day?

Comment: Put it into scheduler/cron, depending on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apscheduler. There are 7 types of schedulers that you can learn about them [here](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html). Background scheduler is one type that I prefer which can be used by the following lines:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(log, 'cron', hours='0-24', id='my_job_id')
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are on linux you could use cron with something like `5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/cron.php`, if you are on windows you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/windows-scheduler-to-run-a-task-every-x-minutes) link.

HTH

Comment: he have GPIO code, i bet it's either embeded linux or some other *nix embeded os. it will surprise me if it's windows. also it's not a good idea to paste a pure link. links expire. it might be gone years later.