# Update all local workspaces with changes to a folder in my project collection

Tags: tfs, workspace, tf-cli, automatic-updates

I have a folder with name "OutputBinaries" inside my project collection. I have local workspaces mapped to this folder on multiple machines. I want to automatically update all these local workspaces whenever there are any modification to "OutputBinaries" folder.

I know tf get command can help if it is specific to a particular machine or a particular workspace. But how this can be accomplished with workspaces on different machines

We are on the latest TFS version

Comment: Binary outputs should not be stored in source control. What are you doing with these binaries? If they are dependencies for applications, you should either manage them as NuGet packages or include them as project references.

Comment: Could you map it to a network share instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as Daniel mentioned above:

> "Binary outputs should not be stored in source control. If they are
>   dependencies for applications, you should either manage them as NuGet
>   packages or include them as project references."

For you specific question,  we can only run the [`tf get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) command in particular workspace on the specific machine.

To update all local workspaces you can try to create a batch script with [`tf get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) command. Then run it periodically on each machine. You can set that with **Windows Task Scheduler**, see [How to schedule a Batch File to run automatically in Windows](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7) for details.

Also this thread for your reference : [Run a task every x-minutes with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler)