# Visual Studio TFS - Prevent check-out if destination is not the latest file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Basically, to prevent conflicts, I want visual studio to warn me if I'm checking out a file but I don't have the latest server version. Currently, it lets me check the file out with no notification, message, or warning. Is this possible to do?

Visual Studio Pro 2015 (14.0.25422.01 U3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by configuring the **checkout settings**:

1. In **Team Explorer**, select and connect to the team project for
   which you want to configure check-out settings.
2. Click **Settings** in Home page
3. From the **Setting** menu, under **Team Project** click **Source
   Control**.
4. In the Source Control Settings dialog box, select the **Check-out
   Settings** tab.
5. Select the **Enable get latest on check-out** box.
6. Click OK.

Thus it will prompt you to select the latest (server) version when you check out file for edit.

---

**UPDATE:**

You don't need the  "AdminProjectRight", just  have the **Edit project-level information** permission set to **Allow**. See [Configure Check-Out Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/configure-check-out-settings).  So, you can ask the admin to set the permission if possible. There isn't a way to set the warning locally, it's project level setting. It needs connecting to TFS to check whether the local version is the latest or not.

Actually you can see that if the local version is not the latest version, then the latest cloumn should be "**No**". So, you can **get latest** first then **check out for edit**.

Another workaround is writing a script with [tf get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) command,then auto run the script periodically, thus the local version will always be the latest version. See below articles to set the auto run task:

- [How to schedule a Batch File to run automatically in Windows
  10/8/7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7)
- [Run a task every x-minutes with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler)

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to do this since I don't have "AdminProjectRights" for the project. Is it possible to do it only locally or is this solely a project-wide setting?

Comment: @DownvoteMe You don't need the  "AdminProjectRight", just  have the **Edit project-level information** permission set to **Allow**.  So, you can ask the admin to set the permission if possible. There isn't a way to set the warning locally, it's project level setting. It needs connecting to TFS to check whether the local version is the latest or not.

Comment: I followed your "Configure Check-Out Settings" link and the page had a link at the bottom which led to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385989 . I followed the steps there which does exactly what I wanted. Steps: Controlling Check-Out Behavior for Your Computer
The following procedure controls the check-out behavior for your computer. This affects all Team Foundation Server clients that are installed on your computer. This includes the tf.exe command line utility and third-party client software.
To enable or disable get latest on check-out for your computer: (cont)

Comment: From the Tools menu, click Options.
In the Options dialog box, expand Source Control and select Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.
Select or clear the Get latest version of item on check out box.
Click OK.