# TFS Force a get latest before a merge

Tags: tfs, merge, tfs-2015

In TFS2015 I have 2 branches:

**Main** & **Release**

Main contains development code and developers are required to merge Main into Release.

We've had a couple of instances recently where devs have not bothered getting latest of Release before performing their merge from Main to Release. This has caused a few headaches as bodged merges have gone in.

Does anyone know of any automated policies that could be put into place that would stop a merge to the target branch unless the dev has the latest version downloaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such an existing policy to restrict the merge. You need to write your own policy if possible. There is a sample for your reference: [Merge / Branch Only Check in Policy](http://leon.mvps.org/TFS/MergeOnlyPolicy.aspx)

Another workaround is creating a script with [tf get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) command to get latest version, then auto run the script periodically, thus the local version will always be the latest version. See below articles to set the auto run task:

- [How to schedule a Batch File to run automatically in Windows
  10/8/7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7)
- [Run a task every x-minutes with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler)