# How to automate the TFS checking other than coding?

Tags: c#, tfs, checkin

Is there any sort of way for auto-checking in the TFS files other than coding?

If no other solution is available can someone please suggest me the best C# code for doing it?

Comment: I do not think it's possible to do an automatic check-in in TFS because you need to tell when your code is correct to be committed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a script/batch file with the [Checkin command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/checkin-command?view=vsts).

e.g.:

```
tf Checkin $source_dir /comment:"Publish new version details" /noprompt /force
```

Then create a [Schedule task to run the batch file automatically](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7).

You can also reference this thread to set the schedule task : [Run a task every x-minutes with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: @user3411135 Have you resolved the issue? any update?