# Notification to get changed files?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

We are a small dev team supporting a few apps in visual studio.  All code changes are checked-in to a VSTS account.

The project I work on is mostly maintained by myself, occasionally by another developer, so I rarely do a full 'get' and only check-out files when I need to change them.

Is there an easy/automatic way for me to be alerted that another developer has checked-in files and prompt me to do a get or compare the changes?

In classic Visual Basic, VSS could be set to do a 'full get' everytime the IDE is opened - always ensuring all developers have the latest code.

Is there nothing similar in Visual Studio?  Even just a notification that my working copy is different to the checked-in version would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try switching to **Server workspace**, then In Visual Studio you can enable the option `Get latest version of item on check-out in a server workspace` (It's not available for Local workspace).

If you are using Local workspace, as a workaround you can try writing a script with [**tf get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command?view=vsts) command,then auto run the script periodically, thus the local version will always be the latest version. See below articles to set the auto run task:

- [How to schedule a Batch File to run automatically in Windows
  10/8/7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7)
- [Run a task every x-minutes with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler)

[image]

If you want to get a notification when others check in the changes, then you can create a subscription:

Navigate to specific project -> Manage -> Notifications -> New subscription -> ...
Select the proper **Deliver to** as needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try the notification method to see if it works for me.
I still miss 'get all on opening solution' option from the old days.