# Run a script on task scheduler when RAM usage is 3gb >

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

as the title says, how do you run a script on task scheduler when RAM usage is greater than 3gb? I want to run a script that changes the power plan (already done).

My only problem is do I configure task scheduler to read RAM usage

Thanks!!

EDIT: I'm experimenting on this

```
while($true) {

$ram = 0

$ram = wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory

if ($ram -ge 12000000) {
powercfg /s 9897998c-92de-4669-853f-b7cd3ecb2790
write-host("AMD balanced")
}

elseif ($ram -le 12000000){
powercfg /s a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
write-host("power saver")

}

write-host($ram)

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I already created scripts that I can run and change the powerplan. My only problem is how do the task scheduler detect the ram usage

Comment: Task scheduler cannot detect the RAM usage, but it can detect and event being logged. If you find out a way to monitor your RAM, logging an event in case of high RAM your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an issue with running this in Task Scheduler, but you'll need to follow this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler) to configure it to run periodically.

I don't recommend running `wmic` because it will pop up a window, but `powercfg` may too. You might be able to set the power plan another way through PowerShell, but this should give you what you're looking for using `Get-WMIObject`.

```
$SysMem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Property FreePhysicalMemory

If($SysMem.FreePhysicalMemory -ge (3 * 1gb)) {
    Write-Host ("AMD Balanced")
    powercfg /s 9897998c-92de-4669-853f-b7cd3ecb2790
} else {
    Write-Host ("Power Saver")
    powercfg /s a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
}
```

This [offsite article](https://facility9.com/2015/07/controlling-the-windows-power-plan-with-powershell/) covers more power plan information.