# How can I reload the URL data within python script, or re-run the script hourly?

Tags: python, windows, flask, scheduler

I am scraping data from a URL where the content often changes and serving up a page in Flask.
What is the best strategy to re-scrape the data and send it to Flask every hour?
Note: running this in a virtual env in Windows cmd.

- Should I use APSchedule?
- Windows task scheduler? (And if so how would I kill the current running script?)
- Or is there some way to periodically reload and update the data within the script?
  (And if so can you please show a specific implementation in the script below? I am struggling to learn python.)

I tried some examples with APSchedule, but had no luck.
Code below

```
#News feed test for Xibo Signage
from flask import Flask, render_template
from markupsafe import Markup
app=Flask(__name__) 
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime

# datetime object containing current date and time
# dd/mm/YY H:M:S
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

url = "https://news.clemson.edu/tag/extension/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)
picture=[]
for e in soup.select('article img.lazyload'):
    sorce = (e.get('data-src'))
    picture.append(sorce)


title=[]
for e in soup.select('article header'): 
    etitle =  (e.find("h3", class_="entry-title bold").text)
    title.append(etitle)
    #    print(e.find("h3", class_="entry-title bold"))
pictures = picture
titles = title

@app.route('/') 
def home():
    return render_template('home.html',pictures=pictures, titles=titles, current_time=current_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I cannot figure how to properly put the functions into the scheduler job. I got the script to run as follows, but it is not updating the time/date on the flask page.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

def sensor():
    """ Function for test purposes. """
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    print("Scheduler is alive!")

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(sensor,'interval',minutes=5)
sched.start()
```

It only sets the datetime once when I initially run the script.

Comment: See [Run a task every x-minutes with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler) or [Creating a scheduled task in Windows that will run at intervals indefinitely](https://superuser.com/questions/403595/creating-a-scheduled-task-in-windows-that-will-run-at-intervals-indefinitely). The hourly script is one-shot and dumps the data to a file which Flask (which is running indefinitely) reads and serves on each request. Can you share your APSchedule attempt and explain what "no luck" entails?

Comment: So if I want to update the time/date for example and send it to the Flask page, how do I put that into a job that the scheduler can run? Please see edit above.

Comment: When you say "formatting errors"--do those errors have a stack trace? If so, please post it in full. The stack trace tells you exactly what the problem is. If you're using Windows Scheduler, you don't need APScheduler. Also, don't use `render_template` in the scheduler. That's a Flask thing. The scheduled task's job is to retrieve data, which gets to Flask via either an in-memory data structure, or as a file as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: When I run the script I get:     now = datetime.now()
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.

Comment: That's a basic syntax error. Your current code doesn't produce that error, so I'd use the code as you posted it. Don't use tabs.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the tab error and got the script to run, but cannot get the datetime variable to update from the scheduler job. Code above.

Comment: Where is the Flask route in your scheduler code?

Comment: BTW, there's an extension that the [APScheduler docs suggest](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/faq.html?highlight=flask#how-do-i-use-apscheduler-in-a-web-application), Flask-APScheduler, which has a [basic example](https://viniciuschiele.github.io/flask-apscheduler/rst/usage.html) in their docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I'd run the job as a one-off script with Windows Task Scheduler, cron, or a GitHub Action and write the data to a file. Then, I'd have the Flask app read the file and serve the data when requested.

But if you want the task to run within the Flask app, optionally without file persistence, you can arrange it as follows using [Flask-APScheduler](https://viniciuschiele.github.io/flask-apscheduler/rst/usage.html):

```py
# python 3.10.12
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask # 3.0.2
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler # 1.13.1


class Config:
    SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = True


class Time:
    now = datetime.now()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config())
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.start()


@scheduler.task("interval", id="sensor", seconds=5)
def sensor():
    Time.now = datetime.now()
    print("job ran:", Time.now)


@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"last_job_time": Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Sample output after starting the server:

```
$ curl localhost:5000
{"last_job_time":"13/03/2024 12:10:11"}
$ curl localhost:5000
{"last_job_time":"13/03/2024 12:10:11"}
$ curl localhost:5000
{"last_job_time":"13/03/2024 12:10:16"}
$ curl localhost:5000
{"last_job_time":"13/03/2024 12:10:16"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did end up using a solution with APScheduler. The key for me also involved using global variables in the schedule job as well as the flask route.

Answer (score 0):

Try nssm.exe to transform your app into a service, which can run with Windows starts and in the background.

I simply use `choco` to install nssm.exe:

```
choco install nssm
```

Then restart your shell, type:

```
nssm install flask
```

A simple GUI will pop up. Just set your python program in a command-line form.